# Python ThreadPoolExecutor submit syntax

Tags: python, for-loop

In reading about Python ThreadPoolExecutors, I found this very helpful page:

https://pymotw.com/3/concurrent.futures/

Most of it I understand after reading and trying some of the examples.  There is one snippet, however, that I'm lost on.  In the section titled: **Waiting for Tasks in Any Order**

There is this:

```
wait_for = [
    ex.submit(task, i)
    for i in range(5, 0, -1)
]
```

I can see what it's doing but I don't understand why it works.  Why is the ex.submit BEFORE the "for" loop?  I've not seen this Python syntax before and I've not found any other examples like this so far.

Comment: Search for "list comprehension"

Comment: @MichaelButscher  That helped a lot!  Please make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to compactly create a list. It consists of an expression producing the items of the list, one or more for-loops to iterate over something that provides the base data for the expression and optionally an if-expression to filter unwanted items.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It was not at all clear to me that this was Python's flavor of list comprehension.  90% of the battle is knowing what to look for.  I found this page that really helped explain it: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html

Answer (score 2):

this code as similiar as this:

```py
wait_for = []
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    wait_for.append(ex.submit(task, i))
```

when loop is over, there are 5 object in `wait_for` if the capacity of ThreadPool more than 5.

Comment: I didn't accept this answer because it doesn't address the question.  I understood what the code was doing, what I didn't understand was WHY.  The comment and later answer on "list comprehensions" pointed me in the right place.